# Google Custom Search and Opensearch

Tags: google-search, opensearch

I have a Google Custom Search Engine on our site and I have recently implemented the opensearch XML file so that I can add our site's search in the browsers' search box.

Any idea how I can add the autocomplete / suggestion feature to the browsers' search box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already enabled "autocompletions" on your Google CSE search engine configuration.

The next step is to add a `Url` element with the `type` "application/x-suggestions+json" in the `OpenSearchDescription` element. I looked into this a little, and the following URL seems like it should work (be sure to enter your own partnerid where it says `[YOUR PARTNER ID]`:

```
http://www.google.com/complete/search?q={searchTerms}&partnerid=`[YOUR PARTNER ID]`&ds=cse&output=firefox
```

e.g.,

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    ...
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template="http://www.google.com/complete/search?q={searchTerms}&amp;partnerid=#YOURPARTNERID#&amp;ds=cse&output=firefox"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Here's [a little webapp](http://customsearchprovider.appspot.com/create.jsf?name=thearchitect%27s+search&searchTemplate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcse%3Fcx%3D%23YOURPARTNERID%23%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3D%7BsearchTerms%7D%26sa%3DSearch&suggestionTemplate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D%7BsearchTerms%7D%26partnerid%3D%23YOURPARTNERID%23%26ds%3Dcse%26output%3Dfirefox&icon=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Ffavicon.ico) I created (pre-populated with some helpful values) to help you with your OSDD.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jack Leow but this did not work.
I tried to access the suggestions from the browser to see if that works first using the url in the "template" attribute. Here is what happened:

http://www.google.com/complete/search?q=searchquery&partnerid=CUSTOM-SEARCH-ID&ds=cse&output=firefox

did not generate any results but 

http://www.google.com/cse?cx=CUSTOM-SEARCH-ID&q=searchquery

works

Note that our CSE is a business edition and I post the results to our own page and also, in the xml, you have to replace '&' with '&amp;'

Thanks

Comment: Google provided some help with the following URL : http://www.google.com/complete/search?q={searchterm}&client=partner&partnerid=000000000000000000000:xxxxxxxxxxx&ds=cse

This does not support the output parameter and I might resort to creating a new intermediary page to format the results for firefox

Comment: That's an option. Sorry about my lack of response, I created a Custom Search Engine account, and enabled autocomplete, but am still waiting for the autocomplete feature to be activated.

Comment: My autocomplete list finally got populated, and I think you're right, you're going to need to create a proxy/intermediary page to strip out the callback function. I can't get Google to generate the search suggestions list without a callback function.

Comment: Does anybody knows what happened to the namespace: http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/ ? It's returning 404 here...